# XSD.exe inheritance properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I'm trying to create a schema file using XSD.exe against a class that has a set of members that all inherit from an abstract class.  What I am finding is that although the abstract class is defined in the schema file, it's properties are not accessible in derived types, when validating XML against the schema.

The exception I get is:

> "The element 'findElement' has invalid child element 'plugins'. List of possible elements expected: 'webElement'."

To help illustrate, I will provide some of the C# code, and parts of the schema which XSD.exe generates.

**Code - Derived Type**

```
[Serializable]
public class FindElement : BaseExecutable
{
    private IWebElement _element = null;
    private TimeSpan _waitTimeout;
    private object _option = null;
    private WebElement _webElement = null;

    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("FindElementType")]
    [XmlElement("id", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("className", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("cssSelector", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("linkText", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("name", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("partialLinkText", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("tagName", typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("xpath", typeof(string))]
    public object Option
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._option is ISDriver)
                (this._option as ISDriver).Root = base.Root;

            return this._option;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is ISDriver)
                (value as ISDriver).Root = base.Root;

            _option = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("useWait")]
    public bool UseWait { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("waitTimeout"), DefaultValue(0)]
    public long WaitTimeoutMilliseconds
    {
        get { return (long)_waitTimeout.TotalMilliseconds; }
        set { _waitTimeout = new TimeSpan(value * 10000); }
    }

    [XmlElement("webElement")]
    public WebElement WebElement
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._webElement is ISDriver)
                this._webElement.Root = base.Root;

            return this._webElement;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is ISDriver)
                (value as ISDriver).Root = base.Root;

            this._webElement = value;
        }
    }

    public FindElement()
    {
        this.WebElement = new WebElement { };
    }
}
```

**Code - Base Type**

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseExecutable : ISDriver, ICloneable
{

    private List<Format> _formatters = null;
    private Conditional _conditional = null;

    [XmlAttribute("screenShot"), DefaultValue(ScreenShotType.None)]
    public virtual ScreenShotType ScreenShotType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("screenShotSize"), DefaultValue(ScreenShotSizeType.Tn)]
    public virtual ScreenShotSizeType ScreenShotSizeType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("messages")]
    [XmlArrayItem("message")]
    public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("msgLevel"), DefaultValue(MsgLevelType.Off)]
    public MsgLevelType MsgLevel { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("continueOnFail"), DefaultValue(true)]
    public virtual bool ContinueOnFail { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("plugins")]
    [XmlArrayItem("plugin")]
    public List<Plugin> Plugins { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("conditional")]
    public Conditional Conditional
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._conditional is ISDriver)
                (this._conditional as ISDriver).Root = this.Root;

            return this._conditional;
        }
        set
        {
            // Just in case we added a type later that doesn't implement ISDriver.
            if (value is ISDriver)
                (value as ISDriver).Root = this.Root;

            _conditional = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("expression")]
    public string Expression { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("formatters")]
    [XmlArrayItem("formatter")]
    public List<Format> Formatters
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (ISDriver f in this._formatters ?? new List<Format>())
                f.Root = this.Root;

            return this._formatters;
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (ISDriver f in value)
                f.Root = this.Root;

            this._formatters = value;
        }
    }

    public BaseExecutable()
    {
        this.ContinueOnFail = false;
        this.Plugins = new List<Plugin>();
    }
}
```

From the standpoint of inheritance, "Plugins" is public, and is available in derived types when deserializing.  But now that I am trying to create a schema to enforce the XML, I see that XSD.exe is not emitting a definition that recognizes properties from the base class.

**XSD Schema - Derived Type**

```
<xs:complexType name="FindElement">
  <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
    <xs:extension base="BaseExecutable">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cssSelector" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xpath" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="className" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="linkText" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="id" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="name" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="tagName" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="partialLinkText" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="webElement" type="WebElement" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="useWait" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute default="0" name="waitTimeout" type="xs:long" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

**XSD Schema - Base Type**

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseExecutable">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="messages" type="ArrayOfMessage" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="plugins" type="ArrayOfPlugin" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="conditional" type="Conditional" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="expression" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="formatters" type="ArrayOfFormat" />
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute default="none" name="screenShot" type="ScreenShotType" />
  <xs:attribute default="tn" name="screenShotSize" type="ScreenShotSizeType" />
  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="message" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute default="off" name="msgLevel" type="MsgLevelType" />
  <xs:attribute default="true" name="continueOnFail" type="xs:boolean" />
  <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

**TEST XML File**

```
<sDriver xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" msgLevel="info">
 <packages>
   <package packageName="Google Test">
     <drivers>
       <driver>
         <actions>
           <action screenShot="after">
             <navigate>
               <gotToUrl Url="https://www.google.com/" msgLevel="info" />
             </navigate>
           </action>
           <action name="actionTitleElement" screenShot="after">
             <findElement useWait="false" msgLevel="info">
               <xpath>/html/head/title</xpath>
               <plugins>
                 <plugin name="Custom.Plugin" />
               </plugins>
             </findElement>
           </action>
         </actions>
       </driver>
     </drivers>
   </package>
 </packages>
```

Is there a way to alter the schema, either manually or using XSD.exe to recognize properties from the base type?

Comment: I have the same issue trying to validate XML using Visual Studio. The XML Editor does not recognize the base type properties as valid child elements, and only lists the properties in the derived type as valid elements.
@ISZ did you find a solution for this? Does anyone else know how to get the XML Editor to recognize the base type properties?